# swift How to get Stripe token?

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments

I want to implement **Stripe** Payment gateway. And need to generate token and pass it to backend.

```
private func getToken(){
        let cardParams = STPCardParams()
        cardParams.number = paymentCardTextField?.cardNumber
        cardParams.expMonth = (paymentCardTextField?.expirationMonth)!
        cardParams.expYear = (paymentCardTextField?.expirationYear)!
        cardParams.cvc = paymentCardTextField?.cvc
        STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: cardParams) { (token: STPToken?, error: Error?) in
            guard let token = token, error == nil else {
                // Present error to user...
                return
            }
            self.dictPayData["stripe_token"] = token.tokenId
            print(self.dictPayData)


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Make sure you need to add your **Stripe** publishableKey (live/test)

in **AppDelegate.swift**

```
     import Stripe
       class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate{

       // var navCon: UINavigationController?
        var window: UIWindow?
        func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application la
             STPPaymentConfiguration.shared().publishableKey = "pk_test_DSFDSFSDFDFSDFSDFDSDSF"

            return true
        }
}
```

in my **PaymentView.swift**

**Note:** Use `STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate` for card validation.

```
class PaymentView: UIViewController,STPPaymentCardTextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var paymentCardTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()
}

private func getToken(){
        let cardParams = STPCardParams()
        cardParams.number = paymentCardTextField?.cardNumber
        cardParams.expMonth = (paymentCardTextField?.expirationMonth)!
        cardParams.expYear = (paymentCardTextField?.expirationYear)!
        cardParams.cvc = paymentCardTextField?.cvc
        STPAPIClient.shared().createToken(withCard: cardParams) { (token: STPToken?, error: Error?) in
            guard let token = token, error == nil else {
                // Present error to user...
                return
            }
            self.dictPayData["stripe_token"] = token.tokenId
            print(self.dictPayData)

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am receiving this error. "You did not provide an API key. You need to provide your API key in the Authorization header, using Bearer auth (e.g. \'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY\'). See https://stripe.com/docs/api#authentication for details, or we can help at https://support.stripe.com/." Can u pls guide me on this ? h